# Bulk write performance differences MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, insert, hardware, bulkinsert

I am working on a project where we have to load a large CSV file (~1.6 mil rows) with ~1000 columns each, about 3kb per record into a MongoDB. They are first transformed into geoJSONs and the collection has a 2dsphere index and one more index on timestamp. We then upload them to an express server where we do an insertMany() of 2000 records at once (~8mb) to store the jsons in the database. Performing just the insertMany() operation on my own computer storing 2000 measurements takes 2-3 seconds but this feels to slow. I then tried using the MongoDB atlas free tier but I found that my insert rates diminished to 25-30 seconds. I don't know much about hardware but I feel like the disk write speed is the bottleneck. I have an INTEL SSDSC2BF18 hard drive on my own desktop. I feel like writing at a rate of 300 docs or 8mb/s is very low but I might be wrong. Could somebody help me clarify this issue?

Comment: Are you using an ordered or unordered insert…? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/index.html#execution-of-operations

Comment: Try the [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/) - maybe you can import the CSV file even directly. On my system I can insert more than 120k documents per second (but my documents are much smaller than yours)

Comment: It is expected that free tier would not be as fast as a performant local computer. Why wouldn't you expect this?

Comment: @deceze I have tried it using both an ordered an unordered set but it didn't make much of a difference.

Comment: @D.SM I expected storage space and processing power to be less performant of course but I was not expecting write speeds to be significantly lower since I assume this is dictated by the type of hard disk and not so much by processing power but I could be wrong. In general it just feels like my insert rate is very low and I would like to get some insight into that.

Comment: Sounds like a different question, and one that is too vague to be answered here. I suggest you read up on how to identify bottlenecks in general.